# GridView items not displaying correct images or backgrounds

Tags: android, gridview, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview

I have a grid view which is being populated by a custom adapter (below).  So I am passing an array list of object to the adapter, results of tests.  The results of the tests are based on the variables in each object.  So for example if object type is x then check if y==1, if so it passes etc...  My logic is included below.  My results state that I have 3 fails and 2 passes from my list of five, however, even though the correct id's are displayed in the five grid items, the incorrect icons and backgrounds are being displayed.  Plus if you look at the bottom of my logcat it shows that there are 26 passed and 39 failed?

Can someone please point out where I'm going wrong on this.  Thanks!

```
package adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import rjg.momentum.com.websockets.SharedDefinitions.SensorResult;

public class SensorTestResultAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SensorResult> {

    private static final String m_Tag = SensorTestResultAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String SENSOR1 = "sensor1";
    private static final String SENSOR2 = "sensor2";
    private Context mContext;
    public int mPassed;
    public int mWarning;
    public int mFailed;
    //will be initialised to current sensor list passed in constructor
    private ArrayList<SensorResult> mSensorResultList;


    public SensorTestResultAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SensorResult> sensorResultList){
        super(context, R.layout.sensor_test_result_grid_item, sensorResultList);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mSensorResultList = sensorResultList;
        this.mWarning = 0;
        this.mFailed = 0;
        this.mPassed = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        //SensorHolder
        SensorHolder holder = null;
        //Inflater to inflate the list item
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //Inflating the list item view

        View view = convertView;

        if(view==null){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sensor_test_result_grid_item, parent, false);
        }
        holder = new SensorHolder();

        holder.icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.status_icon);
        holder.id = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sensor_id);

        holder.id.setText(mSensorResultList.get(position).getSensorId());

        Log.i(m_Tag, "List Size: " + mSensorResultList.size());

        for(SensorResult result:mSensorResultList){
            String sensorType = result.getSensorType();

            if(sensorType.equals(SENSOR1)) {

                int driftResult = result.getDriftResult();
                Log.i(m_Tag, "SENSOR1");

                if (driftResult == 0 && result.getComResult() == 0) {
                    Log.i(m_Tag, "Sensor Passed");
                    mPassed+=1;
                     holder.gridBackground.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bkg_sensor_passed));
                    holder.icon.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_passed));
                } else if (driftResult == 1) {
                    Log.i(m_Tag, "Drift Result Alert");
                    mWarning+=1;
                     holder.gridBackground.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bkg_sensor_warning));
                    holder.icon.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_warning));
                } else if (driftResult == 2 || (result.getComResult() != 0)) {
                    Log.i(m_Tag, "Sensor Failed");
                    mFailed+=1;
                     holder.gridBackground.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bkg_sensor_alert));
                    holder.icon.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_alert));
                }
            }else if(sensorType.equals(SENSOR2)){

                Log.i(m_Tag, "SENSOR2");
                int zeroShiftResult = result.getZeroShiftResult();
                //Log.i(m_Tag, "Zero shift result: " + String.valueOf(zeroShiftResult));
                if(zeroShiftResult==0 && result.getComResult()==0  && result.getGaugeResult()==0){
                    Log.i(m_Tag, "Sensor Passed");
                    mPassed+=1;
                     holder.gridBackground.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bkg_sensor_passed));
                    holder.icon.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_passed));
                }else if(zeroShiftResult==1){
                    Log.i(m_Tag, "Zero shift Result Alert");
                    mWarning+=1;
                     holder.gridBackground.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bkg_sensor_warning));
                    holder.icon.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_warning));
                }else if(zeroShiftResult==2 || result.getComResult()!=0){
                    Log.i(m_Tag, "Sensor Failed");
                    mFailed +=1;
                    holder.gridBackground.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bkg_sensor_alert));
                    holder.icon.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_alert));
                }
            }
        }

        Log.i(m_Tag, "Passed: "+ String.valueOf(mPassed));
        Log.i(m_Tag, "Warning: "+String.valueOf(mWarning));
        Log.i(m_Tag, "Failed: "+String.valueOf(mFailed));
        //Return the view;
        return view;
    }

    static class SensorHolder{
        ImageView icon;
        TextView id;
        RelativeLayout gridBackground;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public int getPassedAmount(){return this.mPassed;}

    public int getWarningAmount(){return this.mWarning;}

    public int getFailedAmount(){return this.mFailed;}
}
```

This is my logcat:

```
02-25 16:19:29.730  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ List Size: 5
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕  SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Passed: 2
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Warning: 0
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Failed: 3
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ List Size: 5
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.740  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.750  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.750  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.750  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.750  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR
02-25 16:19:29.750  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.750  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Passed: 4
02-25 16:19:29.750  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Warning: 0
02-25 16:19:29.750  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Failed: 6
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ List Size: 5
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Passed: 6
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Warning: 0
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Failed: 9
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ List Size: 5
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Passed: 8
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Warning: 0
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Failed: 12
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ List Size: 5
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.780  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Passed: 10
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Warning: 0
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Failed: 15
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ List Size: 5
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Passed: 12
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Warning: 0
02-25 16:19:29.790  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Failed: 18
02-25 16:19:29.810  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ List Size: 5
02-25 16:19:29.810  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.810  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Passed: 14
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Warning: 0
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Failed: 21
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ List Size: 5
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Passed: 16
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Warning: 0
02-25 16:19:29.820  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Failed: 24
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ List Size: 5
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Passed: 18
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Warning: 0
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Failed: 27
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ List Size: 5
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Passed: 20
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Warning: 0
02-25 16:19:29.830  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Failed: 30
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ List Size: 5
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕  SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Passed: 22
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Warning: 0
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Failed: 33
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ List Size: 5
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Passed: 24
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Warning: 0
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Failed: 36
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ List Size: 5
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.840  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.850  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.850  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Failed
02-25 16:19:29.850  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR2
02-25 16:19:29.850  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.850  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ SENSOR1
02-25 16:19:29.850  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Sensor Passed
02-25 16:19:29.850  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Passed: 26
02-25 16:19:29.850  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Warning: 0
02-25 16:19:29.850  31599-31599/rjg.momentum.com.rjgsensortest I/SensorTestResultAdapter﹕ Failed: 39
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i've understood correctly, then I think the issue is that you're processing (iterating through) all your results every time you call your getView() method, rather than the single result you want.

Instead of

```
for(SensorResult result:mSensorResultList){
        String sensorType = result.getSensorType();
...
```

Try String

```
sensorType = mSensorResultList.get(position).getSensorType();
```

Comment: thank you, this resolve my images issue, however, on my logcat it iterates 13 times and now my failed is equal to 11 and passed = 2, any ideas?

Comment: I don't think the numbers you get out of the log are accurate, because when you scroll your listview the getView method will be called on various different positions as they scroll on and off the screen. This will increment your passed/warning/failed variables depending on what the adapter does with your data, rather than just once per data item.

Comment: No worries. If you're consistently seeing the data processed 13 times maybe check your other classes for bugs (where you set the data on the adapter), and/or see how many times your adapter's constructor is called.
Another way you could get more clues into whats going on is to use different data sets of different sizes and see if this affects things.

If there's still things going wrong; trace the code through with the debugger. And if things STILL don't make sense; take a break! You can spend hours on this, have a break, come back and see what's wrong in 5 minutes. Always happens to me.